# Is it possible to set the query parameter name in a controller based on attributes of a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a controller that uses generics. This parent controller is inherited by other child controllers in a generic way by passing the Type of the class they deal with. The actions, in the parent controller, require a parameter bound from a query parameter called partitionKey (Cosmos). Now every type parameter, used with the generic controller, has a different property for the partitionKey (although all are Guids, the names change). The problem is that when the API consumer sees "partitionKey" as the description of the query parameter, they don't have idea which property of all the class Guid properties is the partitionKey.

I thought maybe there could be a way to dynamically set the query parameter name based on an attribute set on the property class that corresponds to the partitionKey. Is it possible to set the query parameter name in a controller based class property attributes? Or is there a better way to do it?

Parent controller

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace x.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class GenericController<T> : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<T>> Get(Guid id, Guid partitionKey)
        {
                var item = await GetItemAsync<T>(id, partitionKey);

                return Ok(item);
        }
```

Child controller

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;


namespace x.API.Controllers
{
    public class GameController : GenericController<Game>
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the name of query parameter at some point, there is no doubt about that. But is it really worth it to make it dynamic? Sounds like overkill to me, when there are still other solutions available achievable with rather little effort.

I said *solutions* because there isn't only one way to do it. But the way I'd do it, is to make the `Get()` method from `GenericController<T>` protected and remove the `[HttpGet]` attribute.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class GenericController<T> : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEntityService _entityService;

    public GenericController(IEntityService entityService)
    {
        _entityService = entityService;
    }

    protected async Task<ActionResult<T>> GetEntity(Guid id, Guid partitionKey)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = await _entityService.GetItemAsync<T>(id, partitionKey);

            return Ok(item);
        }
        catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return NotFound(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers deriving from `GenericController` (here using `Foo` as an example) would call the base `Get()` method. Every derived controller have total control over the method path and it's query parameter names.

```
public class FooController : GenericController<Foo>
{
    public FooController(IEntityService entityService) : base(entityService)
    {

    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Foo>> Get(Guid id, Guid fooKey)
    {
        return await GetEntity(id, fooKey);
    }
}
```

Sample `Foo` entity:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid FooKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in doing as you say, one loses the convenience of just inheriting, you are creating actions in every controller. With the current approach, I just have to declare the inheritance and that's all. The endpoint has the enigmatic partitionKey parameter though, and that is what I want to solve. I thought of adding an attribute to the property in the class that is the partitionKey and then, through reflection, getting the property name and use it for the path or the parameter, but I'm not sure if that is possible.